# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined,

Tags: javascript

```js
var areYouReady = prompt("What do you want to do?").toLowerCase();
var starting_DescriptionStart;
var starting_DescriptorOfThing;
var starting_Thing;
var starting_DescriptionEnd;

if(areYouReady === "generate"){
//Just runs the generator
 
  starting_DescriptionStart = ["You see a"];
   
  starting_DescriptorOfThing = ["Large", "Small", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Black", "White", "Invisible", "Camo", "Striped", "Breathing", "Living", "Sentient"];
   
  starting_Thing = ["Chest", "Snake", "Spider", "Bird", "Bull", "Minotaur", "Sword", "Necklace", "Amulet", "Crown", "Pile of coins", "Deer", "Bunny", "Person", "Goblin", "Orc", "Wizard", "Board", "Ketchup"];

  starting_DescriptionEnd = ["that wants to kill you.", "in a desert.", "on youtube.", "in a dark dungeon.", "in your neighbors house.", "underground.", "in a tree.", "in a restaurant.", ""];
   
   // Random numbers are made 
   var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * starting_DescriptionStart.length);
   var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * starting_DescriptorOfThing.length);
   var randomNumber3 = parseInt(Math.random() * starting_Thing.length);
   var randomNumber4 = parseInt(Math.random() * starting_DescriptionEnd.length);
   generatedArea = starting_DescriptionStart[randomNumber1] + " " + starting_DescriptorOfThing[randomNumber2] + " " + starting_Thing[randomNumber3] + " " + starting_DescriptionEnd[randomNumber4]; 
  
  alert(generatedArea);
 
 
}else if(areYouReady === "add description start"){
 //Lets you add a descriptionStart
 var s_DescStart = starting_DescriptionStart.length + 1;
 
 var inputA = prompt("What do you want to add to the description start");
 
 starting_DescriptionStart[s_DescStart] = inputA;
 
 alert(starting_DescriptionStart[1]);
}
```

I have this code, which is easily addable to via just adding to the arrays, but if I want to make a code that lets the user add to it, and then run it.

When ran this error shows up, after I input "add description start"

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

But, I do not know why it says it's undefined when it's a global variable.

Comment: `starting_DescriptionStart` is undefined in `}else if(areYouReady === "add description start"){` condition.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ahh, thank you! Maybe I should get some sleep if those are slipping past me.

Comment: The title should be a short summary of the problem. *"I can't seem to find what is wrong with this code?"* is a useless title.

Comment: You have declared your variables but not initialised them, therefore they are undefined until you do. As an aside, you should avoid using global variables if at all possible.

Comment: @FelixKling Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In your `else if` statement, you are not defining `starting_DescriptionStart` in any way. It remains undefined, so it does not have a length.

`starting_DescriptionStart` is being declared as a variable at the start of your code, and is only defined in your `if` statement.